# Why is it not undefined behavior that `std::uninitialized_copy` typically dereferences an iterator to uninitialized memory?

Tags: c++, iterator, initialization, dereference

I'm aware that dereferencing a pointer or iterator that points to uninitialized memory is illegal, unless it's a special iterator such as `std::raw_storage_iterator`.

It then seems strange to me that the `std::uninitialized_` family of algorithms seem to do this?
E.g. The *Equivalent behaviour* for `std::uninitialized_copy` under § 23.10.10.4 of the [C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) is stated as this:

> `template <class InputIterator, class ForwardIterator>
>   ForwardIterator uninitialized_copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, ForwardIterator result);`
>
> *Effects*: As if by:
>
> `for (; first != last; ++d_first, (void) ++first)
>      ::new (static_cast<void*>(addressof(*result)))
>         typename iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type(*first);`

Where `result` is a `ForwardIterator` to a range of uninitialized memory.
Similarly, [en.cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy)'s example and [GCC 7.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/libstdc++/api/a00584_source.html) (line 83) do this. I must be missing something; why is this legal? I'm specifically referring to:

`static_cast<void*>(addressof(*result))`

Comment: The memory the iterator refers to has been *allocated*, so it has a valid address, it just hasn't been *populated* with data yet. This is really no different than declaring an array of bytes and then `memcpy()`'ing something into it. It is perfectly legal.  In this case, the code is using `placement-new` to construct an object inside allocated but uninitialized memory.

Comment: The standard library ships with your compiler. It is implemented with the behavior of that compiler in mind. It does not have to be portable code, and it rarely is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `memcpy()` is only perfectly legal if the objects being copied are of a trivial type. The use of placement-new here is fine, my concern was the dereferencing of `result` as I thought it was illegal to dereference a 'dangling' pointer.

Comment: There is no use of a "dangling pointer" in this code

Comment: Apologies, 'dangling' was a poor choice of wording as it implies there's no allocation, which there is. What I meant was that it's not pointing to a valid object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm aware that dereferencing a pointer or iterator that points to uninitialized memory is illegal

Not quite. The indirection alone is not illegal. Behaviour is only undefined in case of performing operations such as those that depend on the value.

`std::addressof` does not access the value of referred object. It only takes its address. This is something that is allowed on objects before and after their lifetime while their storage has been allocated.

Even if this wasn't true due to some technicality in the rules, standard library implementation is not necessarily limited by the rules of the language.

---

Standard quotes (latest draft):

> [basic.life]
>
> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated ... any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be ... located may be used but only in limited ways.
>   For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor].
>   Otherwise, such a pointer refers to allocated storage ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]), and using the pointer as if the pointer were of type void* is well-defined.
>   **Indirection through such a pointer is permitted** but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways, as described below.
>   The program has undefined behavior if: *(no cases that apply here)*
>
> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated ... any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways.
>   For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor].
>   Otherwise, such a glvalue refers to allocated storage ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]), and **using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined**.
>   The program has undefined behavior if: *(no cases that apply here)*

Comment: take `std::vector`.  You can't implement it legally in C++14 and lower.